# Why do I keep getting "The GET method..." when I not using the get method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Why do I keep getting this error?

```
Route::post('/dashboard/project/create/project/1', [DashboardController::class, 'create'])->name('project.create');
```

form:

```
<div class="border-color col-md-10">
    <div class="profile">
        <form action="/sender" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
            <input type="text" name="content"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

link to create

```
<a href="{{route('project.create')}}">Create Project</a>
```

Comment: Clicking on an `<a href="...">` initiates a `GET` request... You only have a `Route::post()` defined...

Answer (score 3):

Your form (`action="/sender"`) is not submitting to the route you posted.

`<a href="{{route('project.create')}}">` opens the route, but using `GET`.

Use the route name in your form's `action` to send your form as `POST`.

```
<div class="border-color col-md-10">
    <div class="profile">
        <form action="{{route('project.create')}}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
            <input type="text" name="content"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```